# C++ fopen fwrite with specific path i choose

Tags: c, fopen, fwrite

I'm writing a simple code on Linux that writes into a file. That file will be stored in specific path ( not the same path where the executable is located ).The problem is that when I execute the code , the program is terminating with **segmentation fault (core dump)**

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  char buffer[] = { 'x' , 'y' , 'z' };
  pFile = fopen ("/home/medwajih/Desktop/bufferfile/buffer.txt", "wb");
  fwrite (buffer , sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), pFile);
  fclose (pFile);
  return 0;
}
```

Note that the exe of the program is in "/home/medwajih/Desktop/"  and the location where I want to create the buffer.txt file is "/home/medwajih/Desktop/bufferfile/"

Thank you.

Comment: You never check the result of `fopen()`. Are you sure it's not `NULL`?

Comment: Does folder `/home/medwajih/Desktop/bufferfile` exist? Write permissions have not been revoked? The file is not locked by another process?

Comment: hello, it works fine now because the executable is in Desktop and the folder "bufferfile" is in Desktop too, but when i use another path for example "/home/medwajih/Downloads/bufferfile/buffer.txt"  the code is terminating with segmentation fault

Comment: @MedWajihSouilem `fopen` will not create missing folders; that's just not `fopen`'s responsibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `fopen` fails (such as if the `/home/medwajih/Desktop/bufferfile` directory does not exist, or the file exists but has permissions that disallow you replacing it), then `pFile` will be set to NULL.

Attempting to use it is then undefined behaviour.

You should generally *check* all calls that may fail to ensure they don't cause issues later on, such as with:

```
pFile = fopen ("/home/medwajih/Desktop/bufferfile/buffer.txt", "wb");
if (pFile == NULL) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Could not create file\n");
    return 1;
}
```

If the problem *is* actually that the directory does not exist, you can call `mkdir` beforehand. And, of course, check the return value of that as well :-)

If it's something else (there's not really enough information in the question to ascertain what it is), you need to find a different way to rectify the problem.

Comment: hello , the directory bufferfile is existing